# Wordpress Categories not showing up on First Post of Front Page and on individual posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am migrating our wordpress host, and I've attempted the migration using both Wordpress Duplicator and Wordpress All-In-One Migration plug-ins. I am seeing that on the new host, the first post on the main page does not have categories, nor do categories show up when I drill in on them. I do know that they have categories because if I click on a category tab, the post is listed in there.

When I turn php error checking on, I see this error:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'add_to_byline' not found or invalid function name in /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298

I am using a theme called Thesis, which has a function add_to_byline() in 
wp-content/themes/thesis_185/custom/custom-functions.php like this:

```
function add_to_byline() { ?>
    </p><p class = "dot_separator">·</p><p class="headline_meta"><?php echo __('', 'thesis') . ' <span>' . get_the_category_list(', ') . '</span>'; ?>
<?php }
add_action('thesis_hook_byline_item', 'add_to_byline', '99');
```

So add_to_byline() does exist, but somehow the new server host is unable to find it, and as a result isn't displaying the categories.

I've diffed the two versions and they are identical minus some white space differences that resulted from debugging. I've also checked file permissions on both old and new server and they are identical. Does anyone have any idea on how I can go about debugging this further?

Comment: Is it only this theme that has problems since the migration? i.e. if you activate the default WP theme, does everything work properly then? Did you check for any instances of `<?` or `<?=` instead of `<?php` ? That can cause problems on different servers. I've also seen an instance of "white space" actually being hidden encoded characters of some kind (usually caused by copy-pasting the code from some other source) so maybe try deleting *all* whitespace in and around that function - its *very* unlikely, but worth a shot if nothing else works.

Comment: Just checked, there were indeed two <? tags but in other functions of the file. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was probably it - finding them is usually the difficult part :) Glad you got sorted!